# How to use onload function in angular js with laravel framework?

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Hello I am new in angularJS and i try to using onload function in angularJS. I created one controller and in that controller using $scope.init for fetch record form mysql database. I am using laravel framework.
This is my view code

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar" ng-controller="NotificationsCtrl"> </div>
```

This is my controller code

```
app.controller('NotificationsCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window, $timeout){

var user_id = sessUser.user_id;
alert(user_id);
$scope.init = function() 
{
    $scope.getNotificationList();
};

$scope.getNotificationList = function() 
  {
    $scope.dataLoading = true;
    $http.get(siteUrl+"notification/getNotificationList/"+user_id).then(function(response) 
    {
      alert(response);
    });
  };
```

});

This is my route

```
Route::get('notification/getNotificationList/{user_id}', 'ProjectController@getNotification');
```

This is my laravel controller

```
public function getNotification($id)
{
    echo $id;
}
```

Please help me i think i make a mistake.

Comment: also where are you calling `$scope.init` function.Also why it is scope function?Scope functions are meant to be used while calling from view only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'ng-init' directive on your markup here's the documentation:

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_directives.asp

just call your init function inside ng-init or just call $scope.init() in the end of your controller

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.init = function() 
{
    $scope.getNotificationList();
};

$scope.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your controller like this.You are not calling your init method.Also no need to write scope function unless using with view.

```
app.controller('NotificationsCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window, $timeout){

var user_id = sessUser.user_id;
alert(user_id);
var getNotificationList = function() 
{
    $scope.dataLoading = true;
    $http.get(siteUrl+"notification/getNotificationList/"+user_id).then(function(response) 
    {
      alert(response);
    });
 };    

var init = function() 
{
    getNotificationList();
};

init(); //call here init
}
```

Comment: when i load this page response shows [object object]

Comment: Console.log the response to see the actual result

Comment: i try you gave code but after load page respose is object object

Comment: Is there any error in console. Next does you request reach at larval.chk these

Comment: @SandipKakade Use ```console.log``` to see the whole object in the Console.